# Visualizing dynamics of 500 translating and rotating spheres

Tags: visualization, simulation, particles

I have used MATLAB to show the dynamics of two spheres that are translating and rotating in space. Here is the youtube link. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uONPJZreQC8&t=82s

I want to extend this to 500 spheres which is extremely slow using MATLAB. I have the position, translational and angular velocity of these spheres for 2000 time steps. Are there any other elegant ways using Paraview or VMD or POVRAY any other softwares ?

Here is an example that I would like to try but don't know how it is made: 
http://ryuon.sourceforge.net/stokes/index.html#visualization